# How to perform an action before a return from a destination view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, viewcontroller

I have the following issue: a source view controller A triggers a destination view controller B
A->B
that in turn turns on the camera and begins scanning barcodes.
Now, the segue used to push the destination view controller (B) is a push one, so, I have a tabbar navigation button allowing me to return to the source view controller (A). I need to make sure that before I return to the source view controller (A) I **switch off the camera**.
This doesn't happen right now (I can see in the console that the camera keeps refocusing despite the control being passed to the source view controller (A)).
How do I do that?
Thanks a lot in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view controller B, add the code to switch off the camera to the `viewWillDisappear` method.

Answer (score 1):

Either way viewDidDisappar or viewWillDisappear will do it for you, make sure to release imagepickercontroller object in the dealloc as and when required.

Answer (score 1):

viewWillDisappear is one option. Another option would be to use `UITabBarController`'s delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```